# After lifetime has ended, recreating an new object, the type of non-static data member of bass class is reference type, is this well-defined?

Tags: c++

Working Draft N4527 3.8[basic.life]p7 says:

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or
>   released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that
>   pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original
>   object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can
>   be used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> (7.1) — the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location which the original object occupied,
>   and
>
> (7.2) — the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
>
> (7.3) — the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, **if a class type, does not contain any non-static
>   data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference type, and**
>
> (7.4) — the original object was a most derived object (1.8) of type T and the new object is a most derived
>   object of type T (that is, they are not base class subobjects).

```
struct B{
    B(int &i):a(i){}
    int &a;
};

struct D:B{
    D(int &i):B(i){}
    f();
};

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    D d(i);
    d.~D();
    new(&d) D(j);
    d.f();  //D does not contain any non-static data member 
            //whose type is a reference type,
            //but B does, is this ok?
    return 0;
}
```

10 [class.derived]p2:

> **Unless redeclared in the derived class, members
>   of a base class are also considered to be members of the derived class**

Question 1:

When the Working Draft says "**non-static data member**", it only means non-static data members of derived class, or of both derived class and base class?

Question 2:

Is the code right?

Comment: `d.~D();` Ouch! As for your 2nd question: No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [class.derived]:

> Unless redeclared in the derived class, members
>   of a base class are also considered to be members of the derived class.

`a` is also a member of `D`, so `D` does contain a non-static data member of reference type. Hence, your usage is invalid.